# error logging per virtualhost

Tags: php, apache

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache. And i want to have separate php-error log per virtualhost. I have read a few stackoverflow topics and set host.com file, but it still doesn't work. PHP errors are logged into error.log and not to php-error.log (I haven't forgot to reboot apache).

My php version: PHP 5.6.30-12~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli).

My host.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost dev.domain.com:443>
ServerName dev.domain.com

ServerAdmin email@domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/dev.domain.com/public_html

ErrorLog /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.access.log combined

php_flag log_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 2147483647
php_value error_log /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.php-error.log

<Directory /var/www/html/domain.com/dev.domain.com/public_html>
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

------EDIT------

Also i have tried like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost dev.domain.com:443>
ServerName dev.domain.com

ServerAdmin linas@hardrokas.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/dev.domain.com/public_html

ErrorLog /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.access.log combined



<Directory /var/www/html/domain.com/dev.domain.com/public_html>
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 2147483647
php_value error_log /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.php-error.log
</IfModule>



SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And this:

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost dev.domain.com:443>
ServerName dev.domain.com

ServerAdmin linas@hardrokas.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/dev.domain.com/public_html

ErrorLog /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.access.log combined



<Directory /var/www/html/domain.com/dev.domain.com/public_html>
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 2147483647
php_value error_log /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.php-error.log
</IfModule>

</Directory>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But same issue, all php errors are logged into error.log

Comment: Restarted your server after making the changes?

Comment: I just catch all the errors and send myself an email ... :), this one time I got like 20k emails though...

Comment: Of course i restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your php_flag values inside directory tag:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost dev.domain.com:443>
ServerName dev.domain.com

ServerAdmin email@domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com/dev.domain.com/public_html

ErrorLog /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.access.log combined


<Directory /var/www/html/domain.com/dev.domain.com/public_html>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 2147483647
    php_value error_log /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.php-error.log    
</Directory>
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Idially try to put those flags inside:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 2147483647
    php_value error_log /var/log/logs/domain.com/dev.domain.com/dev.domain.com.php-error.log
  </IfModule>
```

Or another mod name (depends on php version you are using)

Comment: Still no success. My php version: PHP 5.6.30-12~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli). I have tried to put into <directory> also tired with <IfModule mod_php5.c>

Comment: run script with 

```<?php
phpinfo() ;
```
content. analize error_logsettings. Probably you have rewrite in `htaccess` file